# Previous running processes

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, fedora, openwrt, ps

I need to see the processes that were running on my systems (Ubuntu, OpenWRT, Fedora) at a specific time.
The only way that I am aware of is "ps" which gives me a current snapshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to find something in `/var/log/messages`. Many applications will output a message when they start. Other than that, process starts are not logged by default.

You can however use applications that will log such information. `auditd` is one option, but may be somewhat overkill for your need. A simpler monitoring tool would be [`acct`](http://www.gnu.org/software/acct/). Upon installing and start acct, you can use the command `sa` to get a list of which processes were started by which users at which time.